# Cannot render the function icons inside flatlist - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

icons are not coming.Alert is working.Cannot render the function icons inside flatlist.
pls help.I need your help.

myCode:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.data}
    //extraData={}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
      return index.toString();
    }}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
      <View style={styles.cartView}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touchView} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item.app_link)}>
          <Image style={styles.cartLogo} source={{ uri: item.app_resim }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.mainViewText}>{item.app_name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.mainViewAltBar}>
          <TouchableOpacity >
            <Icon name="refresh-outline" size={30} color="#404040" />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {this.appSet(item.app_namep)}
        </View>
      </View>
    } />

appSet(value){
AppInstalledChecker.isAppInstalledAndroid(value)
.then((isInstalled) => {//not show icons but alert working
  if (isInstalled) {
    return (<Icon name="checkmark-outline" size={30} color="#404040" />);
  } else {
    return (<Icon name="close-outline" size={30} color="#404040" />);
    //alert(isInstalled);
  }
})
```

}

Thank you.

Comment: you can't render the result of a promise, you will need to determine that upfront and save the value in state

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: just change the logic for when you set the data to state to iterate over that data and run `AppInstalledChecker` and save that to state too

Comment: no one is going to be able to give you a more specific answer when the majority of the code is still missing

Comment: Thank you, I will try.